# Colorbar showing time of the day

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am working on scatter plots. I am plotting the colormap based on the time of the day. The problem is the colorbar shows the time as an hour fraction, not as time.

My code:

```
plt.scatter(df[x], df[y], c=df.index.hour+df.index.minute/60, cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The above color bar shows the time as a fraction. For instance, I'd like to show `17:30` instead of `17.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an explicit tick [formatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/ticker_api.html) for the [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html). For example (tested with matplotlib 3.3.1):

```py
plt.colorbar(format=lambda t, pos: f'{math.floor(t):02.0f}:{(t*60)%60:02.0f}')
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Another way to set the tick formatter, which might also work with older matplotlib versions, is to explicitly set a `FuncFormatter`:

```py
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda t, pos: f'{math.floor(t):02.0f}:{(t*60)%60:02.0f}'))
```

Or also:

```py
plt.colorbar(format=plt.FuncFormatter(lambda t, pos: f'{math.floor(t):02.0f}:{(t*60)%60:02.0f}'))
```

Comment: I coded this: `plt.scatter(df[x],df[y],c=df.index.hour+df.index.minute/60, cmap=jet)
    plt.colorbar(format=lambda t, pos: f{math.floor(t):02.0f}:{(t*60)%60:02.0f})` But,  I got the following error: `raise TypeError(formatter argument should be instance of 

TypeError: formatter argument should be instance of matplotlib.ticker.Formatter`

Comment: The first code worked. Thanks a ton. However, I am using matplotlib version 3.0.1. I tried to update it. It gave an error saying permission denied.